# Is there an option when scaffolding tables in ef core, to skip generating foreign key constraints?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using this command in EF core 5 to scaffold out the tables:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=;Database=;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Force -Context -Tables
```

It will generate POCOs and then create properties in those classes based on the foreign key constraints. But I need to skip generating those properties. Are there any options to skip generating these objects?

Answer (score -2):

You can do that with EF Core Power Tools.

But why?

Comment: Because I'm trying to insert junk data for automation testing. I need the POCOs to generate IDs instead of class properties.